# Where did Keras function `slice_X()` go?

Tags: python-2.7, slice, keras

I have a code ([see here](https://github.com/Vladimir-Yashin/keras/blob/13e6a1f99f33a3cc7bc0a44d285fda457cc808e4/keras/callbacks.py)) that uses `slice_X()` (location: keras.engine.training) modifying the common TensorBoard backend (which will lead to OOM (GPU usage)) in order to make use of TensorBoard during GPU usage. 
Unfortunately, since my upgrade to Keras 2.0.0 this will lead to an import error as keras.engine.training doesn't contain `slice_X()` anymore. 
Where did it go? What alternative solution is possible?

I appreciate your help very much.

E D I T:

I have updated the code ([see here](https://github.com/Vladimir-Yashin/keras/blob/13e6a1f99f33a3cc7bc0a44d285fda457cc808e4/keras/callbacks.py)) to Keras 2.0.0 and Tensorflow r1.0.

````
class TensorBoard(keras.callbacks.Callback):
    '''
    Avoids OOM problem.
    Adapted by: https://github.com/Vladimir-Yashin/keras/blob/13e6a1f99f33a3cc7bc0a44d285fda457cc808e4/keras/callbacks.py
    Updated according to discussion:
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42852495/where-did-keras-function-slice-x-go/42855104?noredirect=1#42855104

Tensorboard basic visualizations.
This callback writes a log for TensorBoard, which allows
you to visualize dynamic graphs of your training and test
metrics, as well as activation histograms for the different
layers in your model.
TensorBoard is a visualization tool provided with TensorFlow.
If you have installed TensorFlow with pip, you should be able
to launch TensorBoard from the command line:
```
tensorboard --logdir=/full_path_to_your_logs
```
You can find more information about TensorBoard
[here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/how_tos/summaries_and_tensorboard/index.html).
# Arguments
    log_dir: the path of the directory where to save the log
        files to be parsed by Tensorboard
    histogram_freq: frequency (in epochs) at which to compute activation
        histograms for the layers of the model. If set to 0,
        histograms won't be computed.
    write_graph: whether to visualize the graph in Tensorboard.
        The log file can become quite large when
        write_graph is set to True.
'''

def __init__(self, log_dir='./logs', histogram_freq=0, write_graph=True, write_images=False):
    super(BatchedTensorBoard, self).__init__()
    if K._BACKEND != 'tensorflow':
        raise RuntimeError('TensorBoard callback only works '
                           'with the TensorFlow backend.')
    self.log_dir = log_dir
    self.histogram_freq = histogram_freq
    self.merged = None
    self.write_graph = write_graph
    self.write_images = write_images
    #print(dir(self))

def set_model(self, model):
    import tensorflow as tf
    import keras.backend.tensorflow_backend as KTF

    self.model = model
    self.sess = KTF.get_session()
    if self.histogram_freq and self.merged is None:
        for layer in self.model.layers:

            for weight in layer.weights:
                tf.summary.histogram(weight.name, weight)

                if self.write_images:
                    w_img = tf.squeeze(weight)

                    shape = w_img.get_shape()
                    if len(shape) > 1 and shape[0] > shape[1]:
                        w_img = tf.transpose(w_img)

                    if len(shape) == 1:
                        w_img = tf.expand_dims(w_img, 0)

                    w_img = tf.expand_dims(tf.expand_dims(w_img, 0), -1)

                    tf.image_summary(weight.name, w_img)

            if hasattr(layer, 'output'):
                tf.summary.histogram('{}_out'.format(layer.name),
                                     layer.output)
    if parse_version(tf.__version__) >= parse_version('0.12.0'):
        self.merged = tf.summary.merge_all()
    else:
        self.merged = tf.merge_all_summaries()
    if self.write_graph:
        if parse_version(tf.__version__) >= parse_version('0.12.0'):
            self.writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(self.log_dir,
                                                self.sess.graph)
        elif parse_version(tf.__version__) >= parse_version('0.8.0'):
            self.writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(self.log_dir,
                                                 self.sess.graph)
        else:
            self.writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(self.log_dir,
                                                 self.sess.graph_def)
    else:
        if parse_version(tf.__version__) >= parse_version('0.12.0'):
            self.writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(self.log_dir)
        else:
            self.writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(self.log_dir)

def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
    import tensorflow as tf
    from keras.engine.training import _slice_arrays #original: from keras.engine.training import slice_X
    tf_session = K.get_session()
    #result = []

    if self.validation_data and self.histogram_freq:
        if epoch % self.histogram_freq == 0:
            if self.model.uses_learning_phase:
                cut_v_data = len(self.model.inputs)
                val_data = self.validation_data[:cut_v_data] + [0]
                tensors = self.model.inputs + [K.learning_phase()]
            else:
                val_data = self.validation_data
                tensors = self.model.inputs
            # Sample one batch of validation data to avoid OOM on GPU
            if 'batch_size' in self.params:
                index_array = np.arange(len(val_data[0]))
                batch_ids = np.random.choice(index_array, self.params['batch_size'])
                if self.model.uses_learning_phase:
                    ins_batch = _slice_arrays(val_data[:-1], batch_ids) + [val_data[-1]] #original: slice_X(val_data[:-1], batch_ids) + [val_data[-1]]
                else:
                    ins_batch = _slice_arrays(val_data, batch_ids) #original: slice_X(val_data, batch_ids)
            else:
                # Generators yield one batch at a time and don't provide batch_size
                ins_batch = val_data
            my_feed_dict = dict(zip(tensors, ins_batch))

            result = tf_session.run([self.merged], feed_dict=my_feed_dict)
            #result = self.sess.run([self.merged], feed_dict=my_feed_dict)
            summary_str = result[0]
            self.writer.add_summary(summary_str, epoch)

    for name, value in logs.items():
        if name in ['batch', 'size']:
            continue
        summary = tf.Summary()
        summary_value = summary.value.add()
        summary_value.simple_value = value.item()
        summary_value.tag = name
        self.writer.add_summary(summary, epoch)
    self.writer.flush()

def on_train_end(self, _):
    self.writer.close()
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the `slice_X()` doesn't exist anymore but there is an internal function in `keras.engine.training`: `_slice_array()` that does the job of slicing. See [code here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training.py#L363).

If you have further questions don't hesitate.

**EDIT :**

Here are the two functions.
The old one :

```
def slice_X(X, start=None, stop=None):
    """This takes an array-like, or a list of
    array-likes, and outputs:
        - X[start:stop] if X is an array-like
        - [x[start:stop] for x in X] if X in a list
    Can also work on list/array of indices: `slice_X(x, indices)`
    # Arguments
        start: can be an integer index (start index)
            or a list/array of indices
        stop: integer (stop index); should be None if
            `start` was a list.
    """
```

the new one:

```
def _slice_arrays(arrays, start=None, stop=None):
    """Slice an array or list of arrays.
    This takes an array-like, or a list of
    array-likes, and outputs:
        - arrays[start:stop] if `arrays` is an array-like
        - [x[start:stop] for x in arrays] if `arrays` is a list
    Can also work on list/array of indices: `_slice_arrays(x, indices)`
    # Arguments
        arrays: Single array or list of arrays.
        start: can be an integer index (start index)
            or a list/array of indices
        stop: integer (stop index); should be None if
            `start` was a list.
    # Returns
        A slice of the array(s).
    """
```

What's to understand here is that they basically just changed the name. You edit Vladimir's code just by changing `slice_X()` by `_slice_arrays()` with the same arguments. Also change the import to

```
from keras.engine.training import _slice_arrays
```

I hope it's working now.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help! 
To be honest, I don't know what this `slice_X()` function did. I was treating the piece of code containing `slice_X()` as a black box. 
Now I'm feeling quite uncomfortable to mimic the old function with the new `_slice_array()` since the old hat 2 params and the new one 3 params... :(

Comment: It's the modified TensorBoard callback by Vladimir Yashin. [See here](https://github.com/Vladimir-Yashin/keras/blob/13e6a1f99f33a3cc7bc0a44d285fda457cc808e4/keras/callbacks.py)

Comment: Haha, nice - what a coincidence :D 
Thank you so much. Greetings to Vladimir and many thanks for his work!

Comment: an amazing one indeed. I've edited the answer, can you take a look?

Comment: Thank you! 
Unfortunately, more things changed because of the update of Keras version. Now, I receive the error: `AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute 'validation_data'` which I receive with all my self written callbacks. This sucks.

Comment: You have to replace `self.model.validation_data` by `self.validation_data` (for Keras 2.0.0). 
The new error will be `Fetch argument None has invalid type <type 'NoneType'> at critical line `result = self.sess.run([self.merged], feed_dict = feed_dict)`. 
I have googled, but all advice didn't help (tried renaming)!

Comment: Whooop, whoooop! 
I did it! Can't believe! 
I've put the running version to the EDIT section of my first post. 

Thanks for all the help!